# Best way to handle Category / Subcategory relationship Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Category and Subcategory model. Category has many subcategories and Subcategory belongs to Category. Each subcategory currently has a position field to keep track of where it lines up under the Category it belongs to.

The problem with the way i'm doing it is that each I need the `:position` field to be unique to each category. So instead of using `validates_uniqueness_of :position` in my Subcategory model, I need a way to check that the position field is unique to its specific Category. Anyone have any ideas, or possibly dealt with this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on lucapettes answer,

A nested set (https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set) is something like this :

```
- category
+- category 
+- category 
+--- category 
+- category 
- category
+- category 
+- category 
+--- category 
+- category
```

You can add node to the set anywhere and you would associate your product with any category.

Have a look in this file for the methods https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set/blob/master/lib/nested_set/base.rb

The wiki for awsome_nested_set might have some better docs, https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet

For example you can move an item left, (e.g. up in a list like this ) category.move_left

To understand this model and why it works, read 
[Trees in SQL by Joe Celko](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)

Comment: Thanks, I remember going over trees in school a little bit. Should have paid attention more. Can you advice me when one decides to use NestedList instead of simple belongs_to and has_many relationships?

Comment: Speed is the main advantage with deep trees

Comment: Im working on implementing it, do I put `acts_as_nested_set` in my Category model, Subcategory model, and Product model? and do I need to add the lft, rgt, and parent_id to all of them?

Comment: Or more likely I just add it to my category model, and then my category model will act as the Subcategory and Product in the layout you defined

Answer (score 1):

Use [NestedSet](https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set) for Category/Subcategory handling and [ActsAsList](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) for position handling.

Comment: i'm also going to have Products which belong to subcategories, will NestedSet work with that relationship as well?

Comment: Actually leafs in nested set are already ordered so you can just use a nested set. Yes you can have products in subcategories in this model.

Comment: Added a answer with more details and explanation of nested sets

Answer (score 1):

I believe this validates uniqueness of name based on user id (i.e. name is unique per-user):

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:user_id]
end
```

A simple association as `has_many` and `belongs_to` may work for you. If position is an integer, you can do `order_by :position` in your controller with or without uniqueness of that position.