# Nested Set gem - Do I need it and how to limit depth if so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-sets

I am trying to create my app using the Nested Set Gem [here](https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set) 
I am trying to create a simple product menu for my app, so I would have something like this

+Category 
--Category
----Product
----Product
--Category
----Product
----Product

My problem with the nested Set gem is that I don't want the depth two be more then two category's deep. The nested set gem by default allows something like this

+Category
--Category
---Category
----Category
-----Product

But for our CSS Styling purposes, we don't want to deal with that much depth, and the customer doesn't need that much depth to it.

So i'm wondering if I even need the nested set in the first place, or will a standard has_many belongs_to work in this scenario? I am using Nested Set from the responses to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269086/best-way-to-handle-category-subcategory-relationship-ruby-on-rails).

I am personally under the opinion that I may just use a standard has_many and belongs to, unless someone can inform me an advantage to using Nested Set in my case. If I do need it, how do I limit the customer from only selecting the correct depth to add a node to?

**EDIT:** Solved, Thanks.
My new problem is I am getting the error

**undefined method `self_and_descendants' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
Extracted source (around line #9):**

```
6: </p>
7: <p>
8:   <%= f.label(:parent_id) %>
9:   <%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category.categories, @category) {|i,     level| "#{'-' * level} #{i.name}" } %>
10: </p>
11: <p>
12:   <% # f.label(:position) %>
```

**views/categories/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label(:name) %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label(:parent_id) %>
    <%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category.categories, @category) {|i, level| "#{'-' * level} #{i.name}" } %>
</p>
<p>
  <% # f.label(:position) %>
  <% # f.select :position, 1..category_count %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit("Submit") %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**models/category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set
  acts_as_list :scope => :parent_id
  has_many :products
  scope :position, order("position asc")
  scope :categories, where("parent_id IS NULL")
  scope :subcategories, where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")
end
```

**routes.rb** (Shortened for space)

```
Locksmithing::Application.routes.draw do
resources :categories do
  collection { post :sort }
  resources :children, :controller => :categories, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :new_subcategory]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely continue using nested_set in this kind of context.

I have a hierarchical setup in the app I'm currently working on and while I allow infinite nesting, I only want the nav to show top 2 levels.

I have a named scope to let me limit what I'm looking at:

```
scope :with_depth_below, lambda { |level|
  where(self.arel_table[:depth].lt(level))
}
```

Such that (using Category from your example) you could use

```
Category.with_depth_below(4).arrange
```

You can pass that scope into any of nested_set's scopes - or indeed the View Helper you're probably aiming to use for limiting how many levels it can go.

To genuinely limit it, I'd also just place a validation constraint... before_save, checking that the depth is less than your max depth. Make sense?

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up for me, and I will indeed use nested_set on this app.  Can you clear up the _nested_set's scopes_ for me? Also, Currently my form looks like this, <%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i, level| "#{'-' * level if level < 1 } #{i.name if level < 1 }" } %>. How can I pass in Category.with_depth+below(2).arrange to that the select only grabs the correct Categories with depth 2 or below? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Looking at the code for the helper `nested_set_options` - https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set/blob/master/lib/nested_set/helper.rb - the first argument can be a class (where it'll call it on the whole collection) or an array. You should therefore be able to pass it the scoped collection - either as an instance variable you set up in the controller, or (less preferably) by doing it in the view.

Comment: Thanks now when I try to pass that instance variable in I get the error undefined method `self_and_descendants' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x52c4a30>, Any Ideas?

Comment: `self_and_descendants` is an instance method (i.e. can be called on a particular category object). Maybe post a little more of your code?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I posted a new question to post my code, here is the link. Thanks! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459662/nested-set-error-undefined-method-self-and-descendants-for-activerecordrel)

Comment: see above post, tagged you in it

Comment: I added more code to this question. I still have not figured this out any help would be appreciated