# Nested Set Error undefined method `self_and_descendants' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x52c4a30>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nested-sets

I am using the Nested_Set gem in my code to sort Categories, Subcategories, and Products. I am trying to limit the depth/level of my nested set to no deeper then 2. Currently I am getting the error

```
Nested Set Error undefined method `self_and_descendants' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x52c4a30>
```

I am trying to create a restraunt menu type style, and am going to attempt to make it drag and drop sortable.

Here is my code:
Can someone browse it and help me understand this error? Thanks
    Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set
  acts_as_list :scope => :parent_id
  has_many :products
  scope :category, where("parent_id IS NULL")
  scope :subcategories, where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")
  scope :with_depth_below, lambda { |level| where(self.arel_table[:depth].lt(level)) }
end
```

categories_controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @category = params[:id] ? Category.find(params[:id]).children.new : Category.new
    @count = Category.count
  end

  def new_subcategory
    @category = params[:id] ? Category.find(params[:id]).children.new : Category.new
    @category_2_deep = Category.with_depth_below(2)
  end

  def create
    @category = params[:id] ? Category.find(params[:id]).children.new(params[:category]) : Category.new(params[:category])
    if @category.save
      redirect_to products_path, :notice => "Category created! Woo Hoo!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def edit_subcategory
    @category = Category.find(params[:id]) 
    @category_2deep = Category.with_depth_below(2).arrange
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Category has been obliterated!"
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
      flash[:notice] = "Changed it for ya!"
      redirect_to products_path
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Category has not been updated."
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
  end

  def sort
    params[:category].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Category.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
  end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
Jensenlocksmithing::Application.routes.draw do
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", as: "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", as: "log_in"
  get "site/home"
  get "site/about_us"
  get "site/faq"
  get "site/discounts"
  get "site/services"
  get "site/contact_us"
  get "site/admin"
  get "site/posts"
  get "categories/new_subcategory"
  get "categories/edit_subcategory"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :coupons
  resources :monthly_posts
  resources :categories do
    collection { post :sort }
    resources :children, :controller => :categories, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :new_subcategory]
  end
  resources :subcategories
  resources :products
  resources :reviews
  resources :faqs do
    collection { post :sort }
  end 

  root to: 'site#home'
end
```

categories/form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>

<p>
<%= f.label(:name) %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label(:parent_id) %>
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(@category_2_deep, @category) {|i, level| "# {'-' * level if level < 1 } #{i.name if level < 1 }" } %>

</p>
<p>
<%= f.label(:position) %>
<%= f.select :position, 1..category_count %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit("Submit") %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like nested_set is looking for an Array not just an array-like collection - see line 32 of the source: https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set/blob/21a009aec86911f5581147dd22de3c5d086355bb/lib/nested_set/helper.rb#L32

...hence it's getting that ActiveRecord::Relation, wrapping it in an [array] (line 35) and then trying to iterate and blowing up.

**Easy fix**: call `to_a` on the collection first - in your controller:

```
@category_2_deep = Category.with_depth_below(2).to_a
```

**Better fix**: submit a patch to the maintainer that's a bit more Ruby-like and looks for it to *behave like* an Array, but not necessarily be one.

Comment: I have one more question, the documentation says 'There is no reason to use depth column. It's only add additional queries to DB without benefit. If you need level you should use each_with_level instead.' so How would I do this without a depth column?

Comment: feel free to browse my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116481/need-to-understand-code-that-finds-depth-of-nested-set-in-rails-3-app). I am still having questions because I can't just call the scope I don't have a depth column.